# how can i conver the below SQLQuery into LINO

Tags: linq

```
SELECT     t_PersonalInformation.personalInformation_Name,             t_PersonalInformation.personalInformation_PresentAddress, 
           t_PersonalInformation.personalInformation_PermanentAddress, t_PersonalInformation.personalInformation_Phone, 
           t_PersonalInformation.personalInformation_Email,

           t_Applicant.applicant_TotalExperience,

           t_Experience.experience_CompanyName, CAST( t_Experience.experience_EndingYear AS INT) - CAST( t_Experience.experience_JoiningYear AS INT) AS yearOfExperience ,
           t_Experience.experience_Responsibilities,

           t_Training.training_TitleDetails,   t_Training.training_Institute,
           t_Training.training_Year,           t_Training.training_Duration


FROM         t_Applicant LEFT OUTER JOIN
             t_PersonalInformation ON  t_Applicant.applicant_user_ID = t_PersonalInformation.personalInformation_applicant_ID

             LEFT OUTER JOIN   
             t_Experience          ON  t_Applicant.applicant_user_ID = t_Experience.experience_applicant_ID

             LEFT OUTER JOIN
             t_Training            ON  t_Applicant.applicant_user_ID = t_Training.training_applicant_ID



WHERE     (t_Applicant.applicant_user_ID = 'hasib789')
```

i am using in C# with VS2008

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have the time to go through all of that, but I can give you an idea of how it's done.

```
var query = from var applicant in t_Applicant
    from perInf in t_PersonalInformation.Where(per => applicant.applicant_user_ID = per.personalInformation_applicant_ID).DefaultIfEmpty()
    where applicant.applicant_user_ID == "hasib789"
    select new ClassName{
        Name = perInf!=null ? perInf.personalInformation_Name : <default value>,
        PresentAddress = perInf!=null ? perInf.personalInformation_PresentAddress: <default value>,
        ...
        etc
    }
```

That second 'from' statement is one of the ways to do an outer join. That DefaultIfEmpty allows it to generate a new record of ClassName even if no matching record for perInf is found. Once you actually go to assign the values in your new record at the bottom, you have to check for null.

Using that template you should be able to get the rest of the query built.