# What will be the LINQ query for the below SQL Query

Tags: sql, linq

SELECT     t_PersonalInformation.personalInformation_Name,             t_PersonalInformation.personalInformation_PresentAddress, 
           t_Applicant.applicant_TotalExperience,

```
       t_Experience.experience_CompanyName, 
       t_Experience.experience_Responsibilities,

       t_Training.training_TitleDetails
```

FROM         t_Applicant LEFT OUTER JOIN
             t_PersonalInformation ON  t_Applicant.applicant_user_ID = t_PersonalInformation.personalInformation_applicant_ID

```
         LEFT OUTER JOIN   
         t_Experience          ON  t_Applicant.applicant_user_ID = t_Experience.experience_applicant_ID

         LEFT OUTER JOIN
         t_Training            ON  t_Applicant.applicant_user_ID = t_Training.training_applicant_ID
```

WHERE     (t_Applicant.applicant_user_ID = 'hasib789')

I am working with C# with vs2008 for a asp.net application

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i conver the below SQLQuery into LINO......](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759206/how-can-i-conver-the-below-sqlquery-into-lino)

Comment: Please don't create duplicate users and questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is depend on what mapping do you have.
For example it can be:

```
var result = 
from a in DataContext.Applicant 
 join pi in DataContext.PersonalInformation on a.applicant_user_ID equals pi.personalInformation_applicant_ID
 join e in DataContext.Experience on a.applicant_user_ID equals e.experience_applicant_ID
 join t in DataContext.Training on a.applicant_user_ID equals t.training_applicant_ID
where a.applicant_user_ID == 'hasib789'
select new { personalInformation_Name = pi.personalInformation_Name, personalInformation_PresentAddress = pi.personalInformation_PresentAddress, applicant_TotalExperience = a.applicant_TotalExperience, experience_CompanyName = e.experience_CompanyName, experience_Responsibilities = e.experience_Responsibilities,       training_TitleDetails  = t.training_TitleDetails }
```